# Iterate in list and get nearest values

Tags: jquery, css

How can I loop in the list below and set the values of the  as a class on the input? But it cannot iterate over the .liBrand list item.

```
<ul>
    <li class="liModelFilter liMultipleSelectionFilter">
        <ul>
             <li class="liBrand"><b>Mini</b></li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="1090" id="ModelIds">
                 <span>Cooper</span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="1092" id="ModelIds">
                 <span>One</span>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Required result:

```
<li>
    <input class="Cooper" type="checkbox" value="1090" id="ModelIds">
    <span>Cooper</span>
</li>
```

I need this because I have to create a custom checkbox - each checkbox has to have to logo of the type (Cooper, One,...).

I already tried something like this:

```
jQuery($('.liModelFilter ul li:not(.liBrand)')).each(function() {
    console.log($('.liModelFilter ul li:not(.liBrand)')).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to call `addClass()` on the `input` elements, and provide a function which returns the text content of the sibling `span`, something like this:

```js
$('.liModelFilter :checkbox').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).next('span').text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="liModelFilter liMultipleSelectionFilter">
    <ul>
      <li class="liBrand"><b>Mini</b></li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1090" class="ModelIds">
        <span>Cooper</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1092" class="ModelIds">
        <span>One</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also note that I changed the `id="ModelIds"` to a class, as you cannot have duplicate `id` attributes within the DOM.